# Do we feel compelled to defend objectivity, but not subjectivity, because objectivity is a concept in the domain of the subjects' knowledge?

Tags: knowledge, objectivity, subjectivity, objects, intersubjectivity

**Objectivity**

https://iep.utm.edu/objectiv/

> The object is something that presumably exists independent of the subject’s perception of it. In other words, the object would be there, as it is, even if no subject perceived it. Hence, objectivity is typically associated with ideas such as reality, truth and reliability.

**Scientific Objectivity**

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-objectivity/

> Objectivity is a value. To call a thing objective implies that it has a certain importance to us and that we approve of it. Objectivity comes in degrees. Claims, methods, results, and scientists can be more or less objective, and, other things being equal, the more objective, the better. Using the term “objective” to describe something often carries a special rhetorical force with it. The admiration of science among the general public and the authority science enjoys in public life stems to a large extent from the view that science is objective or at least more objective than other modes of inquiry. Understanding scientific objectivity is therefore central to understanding the nature of science and the role it plays in society.

> If what is so great about science is its objectivity, then objectivity should be worth defending. The close examinations of scientific practice that philosophers of science have undertaken in the past fifty years have shown, however, that several conceptions of the ideal of objectivity are either questionable or unattainable. The prospects for a science providing a non-perspectival “view from nowhere” or for proceeding in a way uninformed by human goals and values are fairly slim, for example.

In the absence of subjects there are no objects of perception to discuss and no subjective concepts called "objective values". Therefore, the whole discussion of objects, objectivity, and objective values seems to be a subdomain of subjective knowledge. Is there a compelling argument for objects, objectivity, or objective knowledge independent of subjects or is this just the subjective belief that objective knowledge exists somehow independent of the knowing subject(s)? In my case reality is anything that seems to oppose my will so that I cannot get whatever it is I want in my field of perceptions by a mere whim or wish. But I do not confuse my field of perceptions with ultimate reality something exists but I don't know its ultimate attributes only its attributes in my mind.

**EDIT - Objectivism - Ayn Rand**

Video lecture:

https://youtu.be/hlJD0i_WwdQ

> Existence exists.

> A is A (the law of identity).

> Reality is reality.

> Reality is reality independent of the conscious mind.

> Reality is objective.

> Objective reality is true: not what people believe to be true.

Reality independent of the mind, objective reality, would not have attributes of true or untrue which are attributes of the mind. I think subjects confuse their mind with something outside the mind.

Comment: To give some different perspective to the question in your title, ", because objectivity is a concept in the domain of subjective knowledge?". Maybe, but also possibly because subjective knowledge arises from experiencing and discerning the objective nature of the world that we are a part of.

Comment: It might also be because as long as one can think, it is quite intuitive and part of the human psyche to sort of intuitively come to Descartes' cogito argument - an argument for establishing 'objectivity'.

Comment: @How why e - When Moses asks God his name, God says, *I Am What Is*. What Is has subjective nature in the mind. The mind may believe that What Is has *objective nature* based on subjective knowledge but otherwise What Is must transcend the subjective knowledge of things with *objective nature*.

Comment: "Subjective knowledge" does not mean what you think it means. It means knowledge confined to a *single* subject, in principle. "Knowledge" already presupposes subjects by definition, so there is no point adding "subjective" to it for that. The compelling argument is that subjects manage to understand what other subjects are talking about, so there must be something "independent" of *individual* subjects, and it cannot be "subdomain of subjective knowledge" confined to each.

Comment: @Conifold - Only single subjects have attributes of knowledge which means all knowledge among one or more subjects is subjective! Q.E.D. Calling something objective in the context of the knowledge of subjects maps to the knowledge of the subjects not to what exists in the absence of the subjects or their knowledge.

Comment: I suggest you question the basic frame of your title question. You could eg. run a web search for "subjectivity+X" where X can be one of {existentialism, Heidegger, post-modernism}

Comment: I'd say we are compelled to distinguish between the two. Often those who value objectivity more than subjectivity only do so when it is somebody else's subjectivity in question! ;o)

Comment: If I understand @Conifold he is saying the knowledge that multiple subjects possess in common is objective knowledge. This knowledge, such as the concept of New York City as a place in the world, does not depend on the existence of any particular subject. But knowledge in general is an attribute or property of subjects. So the distinction between objective knowledge and subjective knowledge maps to the knowledge of subjects. There is no knowledge without any subjects. I think it is confusion in the mind(s) of the subject(s) to imagine attributes of knowledge true independent of subjectivity.

Comment: What would defending subjectivity look like? Can you give an example?

Comment: @TKoL - I don't think we feel compelled to defend subjectivity because we accept that knowledge is an attribute of the subject. The Buddha and Sigmund Freud (the founder of psychoanalysis) were both atheists. But neither the Buddha nor Sigmund Freud would deny the fact that *multiple* other human subjects report their subjective knowledge of God. In my models there are multiple human bodies each alive at some time with a brain integrated into their body via their nervous system.  Knowledge is the product of an ultimately mysterious process which is implicit in the body-mind of each subject.

Comment: @SystemTheory I don't feel like my question was addressed

Comment: @TKoL - I don't feel compelled to defend subjectivity but please do so and provide an example if you feel compelled to do so I will map that desire of yours to something in your subject not to the objective reality or objective knowledge.

Comment: I still don't know what "defend subjectivity" even means.

Comment: @TKoL - So you introduced the term "defending subjectivity", you don't know what it means, and you want me to define what it means to me and to provide an example for you? I did not introduce the term into conversation and I have no idea what it means either.

Comment: How did I introduce it? It's implied in the title of your question. "Do we feel compelled to defend objectivity, but not subjectivity..." - the second half of this is short hand for "but  not defend subjectivity"

Comment: @TKoL - I concede your point it is a valid possible interpretation of my question. But I think also my question implies that we do not feel compelled to defend subjectivity or subjective knowledge - whatever we mean by those terms! I gave examples of how subjects debate and discuss the meaning of objective, objectivity, scientific objectivity, because subjects seem to be compelled to define such knowledge and defend it. I can only comprehend objective knowledge as a subdomain of my knowledge: the knowledge of one subject. And I map the implicit subject to "objects": brains, neurons, bodies.

Comment: The truth doesn't need defending, ignore it at your peril. Objectivity needs defending in the same way that all elements of a functioning society do: to avoid having everything useful that we rely on devolving in to anarchy. Subjectivity could be seen as a foe, in that point of view. We don't want fun experiences, or desired ones, we want experiences that are consistent across many people. You said: "I think subjects confuse their mind with something outside the mind." That they do. But we will never know what is outside the mind, so there's no use arguing about it.

Comment: @Scott Rowe - I agree in broad terms there is no use arguing about what we do not know. People like Ayn Rand confuse what is in their mind, the conceptual, ethical, and moral construction called Objectivism, with some attributes of reality! I imagine that Objectivists imagine that their knowledge of Objectivism is objective!  Sigmund Freud is another clown in the moralistic atheist clown-car. He argues that the ego suffers because it is not well-adjusted to external and social reality. But who defines reality? I would rather go to heaven in a heartbeat with my dog then pay Freud for "therapy".

Comment: "*We're all Bozos on this Bus*". I had a dog that I loved very much. I could walk him anywhere without a leash.